# boost asio tcp - socket write data different from data in buffer - possible thread unsafety somewhere

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I'm exploring the boost asio offerings

the client sends a header of 1 byte indicating the length of bytes to follow.

relevant server code:

```
  enum {max_length=1};     

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code & error, const size_t & bytes_transferred){
if (! error){
  ++ctr;
  std::string inc_data_str(this->inc_data.begin(),this->inc_data.end());
  std::cout<<"received string: "<<inc_data_str<<" with size "<<inc_data_str.size()
           <<" bytes_transferred: "<<bytes_transferred<<" ctr: "<<ctr<<std::endl;
  int size_inc_next = boost::lexical_cast<int>(inc_data_str);
  int offset = 0;
  //std::cout<<"incoming integer of size "<<size_inc_next<<" processed from string: "<<inc_data_str<<std::endl;                    
  std::vector<char> next_inc_data(size_inc_next+offset);
  boost::asio::read(this->socket,boost::asio::buffer(next_inc_data),boost::asio::transfer_exactly(size_inc_next+offset));
  std::string int_recvd(next_inc_data.begin(),next_inc_data.begin()+size_inc_next);
  //std::cout<<boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()<<std::endl;                                                         
  //std::cout<<"received integer: "<<int_recvd<<" from string "<<int_recvd<<" of size "<<int_recvd.size()<<std::endl;              
  this->process_connection();
 } // ! error
} // handle_read

void process_connection(){
                                                   boost::asio::async_read(this->socket,boost::asio::buffer(this->inc_data),boost::asio::transfer_exactly(max_length),
                    boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read,shared_from_this(),boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

relevant client code:

```
  void on_write(const boost::system::error_code & error_code){
if (! error_code){
  std::string transfer_data("15");
  std::vector<char> v_td(transfer_data.begin(),transfer_data.end());
  ++ctr;
  for (std::vector<char>::iterator iter = v_td.begin(); iter != v_td.end(); ++iter) std::cout<<*iter;
  std::cout<<" ctr: "<<ctr;
  std::endl(std::cout);
        boost::asio::async_write(this->socket,boost::asio::buffer(v_td),boost::asio::transfer_exactly(2),
                           boost::bind(&Client::on_write,shared_from_this(),
                                       boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }
 }
```

Expected example printing output for Server process:

```
  received string: 1 with size 1 bytes_transferred: 1 ctr: 159685
```

Expected example printing output for Client process:

```
  15 ctr: 356293
```

Such expected output is produced for a while, but say after say 356293 client iteration (this ctr number is non-deterministic to the naked eye from repeated trials of the processeses), the server breaks with the following error:

```
 received string:  with size 1 bytes_transferred: 1 ctr: 159686
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_lexical_cast> >'
 what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

Aborted (core dumped)

Note that the received string is "blank". 
On occasions it also breaks with the alternative message:

```
 received string: X with size 1 bytes_transferred: 1 ctr: 159686
```

What's going on here and why and how do i sort it out ?

Further EDIT after strace:

Client trace:

```
 sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"15", 2}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 2
 epoll_wait(4, {}, 128, 0)               = 0
 write(1, "15 ctr: 204441\n", 1515 ctr: 204441)        = 15
 sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"15", 2}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0},    MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 2
 epoll_wait(4, {}, 128, 0)               = 0
 write(1, "15 ctr: 204442\n", 1515 ctr: 204442)        = 15
 sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"15", 2}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily \
 unavailable)
 epoll_wait(4, {{EPOLLOUT, {u32=167539936, u64=167539936}}}, 128, -1) = 1
 sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\0\0", 2}], msg_controllen=0,   msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 2
 write(1, "15 ctr: 204443\n", 1515 ctr: 204443)        = 15
 sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"15", 2}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0},     MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 2
 epoll_wait(4, {}, 128, 0)               = 0
 write(1, "15 ctr: 204444\n", 1515 ctr: 204444)        = 15
 sendmsg(6, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"15", 2}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 2
 epoll_wait(4, {}, 128, 0)               = 0
 write(1, "15 ctr: 204445\n", 1515 ctr: 204445)        = 15
```

Server trace:

```
 write(1, "received string: 1 with size 1 b"..., 64received string: 1 with size 1   bytes_transferred: 1 ctr: 204441) = 64
 write(1, "incoming integer of size 1 proce"..., 52incoming integer of size 1 processed from string: 1) = 52
 recvmsg(7, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"5", 1}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0},0) = 1
 write(1, "received integer: 5 from string "..., 44received integer: 5 from string 5 of size 1) = 44
 recvmsg(7, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"1", 1}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0},0) = 1
 epoll_wait(4, {}, 128, 0)               = 0
 write(1, "received string: 1 with size 1 b"..., 64received string: 1 with size 1 bytes_transferred: 1 ctr: 204442) = 64
 write(1, "incoming integer of size 1 proce"..., 52incoming integer of size 1 processed from string: 1) = 52
 recvmsg(7, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"5", 1}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 1
 write(1, "received integer: 5 from string "..., 44received integer: 5 from string 5 of size 1) = 44
 recvmsg(7, {msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\0", 1}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 1
 epoll_wait(4, {}, 128, 0)               = 0
 write(1, "received string: \0 with size 1 b"..., 64received string: ^@ with size 1 bytes_transferred: 1 ctr: 204443) = 64
 futex(0xb76640fc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
 write(1, "inc_data_str\n", 13inc_data_str)          = 13
```

For the client process, the epoll_wait before the erroneous "\0\0" send is different (u32=...., u64=....) than from the other epoll_wait calls ... don't know what that means though

To sum up the baffling part, the strace indicates nulls being transferred, yet the strace the next line indicates a write system call to standard output with the literal "15" which means that's what was in the transfer_data vector

Re-EDIT:

Finally I inserted a

```
  boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::microseconds(200));
```

just before the write statement in the client on_write function.

With this, no problems were faced. So what sort of concurrency issue could this be with the asio objects ? is it the socket?

Comment: Your server design is strange. You use `async_read()` for reading the header, but then a blocking synchronous `read()` for reading the body. I'd suggest using `async_read()` for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your client is broken because of buffer lifetime

```
void 
on_write(
    const boost::system::error_code& error_code
)
{
    if ( !error_code ) {
        std::string transfer_data("15");
        std::vector<char> v_td(transfer_data.begin(), transfer_data.end());
        //                 ^
        //                  \------ goes out of scope before async_write() returns

        boost::asio::async_write(
            this->socket,
            boost::asio::buffer(v_td),
            boost::asio::transfer_exactly(2),
            boost::bind( 
                &Client::on_write,
                shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
            )
        );
     }
 }
```

You need to ensure the buffer given to [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) remains valid until the completion handler is invoked:

> **buffers** One or more buffers containing the data to be written. Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of
>   the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must
>   guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called. handler

---

Answer (score 0):

Well, the exception message says, there is a bad lexical cast. I see one in your server code:

```
int size_inc_next = boost::lexical_cast<int>(inc_data_str);
```

Maybe you should put a breakpoint there and debug. When you get the message

> received string: X with size 1 bytes_transferred: 1 ctr: 159686

it's obviously the output of the line before the `lexical_cast`. Then `inc_data_str` seems to be "X" - and casting that to an int should trigger that bad cast exception.

Why there is an "X" coming from the other side of the connection I can't tell.

Comment: yes exactly ! it's baffling cause the client has a hardcoded "15" being transfered ...

Comment: I don't see the call to `async_read` in your server, so I'd have to guess: coud it be that the client did not only transfer the "1" in the first run? Or generally that the data you send are not "in sync"? What's in the `int_recvd` after the first call to `read()` in the read handler of the server? You'll have to debug that.

Comment: i did an strace on both procs. The client is always writing "15", but at the time of the bug in the server, it reads a null "\O", instead of a "1". that was a faulty copy paste of the async_read, just edited that. thank you.

Comment: O wait ! the client writes "\0\0" at one point in the middle, before again reverting back to "15" ... how ?

Comment: seems the buffer somehow is empty. And since youw ant the client to *exactly* write two characters, it writes zeroes.

Comment: ok that makes sense. but how is the buffer empty ? it's instructed to lift transfer data containing "15" ?

Comment: is the issue repeatable? The the best you can do is use a debugger and find out.

Comment: i'll try. To sum up the baffling part, the strace indicates nulls being transferred, yet the strace the next line indicates a write system call to standard output with the literal "15" which means that's what was in the transfer_data vector ... weird

Comment: I suspect it's a concurrency issue ? Cause when I slowed down the writes in the client by inserting a boost::this_thread:sleep, things don't break ... any ideas

Comment: I can't tell from the code you posted. Maybe provide the full source of client and server on pastebin or liveworkspace?